# Как сконструировать поля производного класса?

Tags: c++, qt, ооп

В базовом классе имеется указатель `QChart *m_chart`. В производном классе он должен иметь тип `QPolarChart`, который является производным от `QChart`. К этому полю обращается как базовый класс, так и производный. Как правильно переопределить конструктор, чтобы поле `m_chart` в производном классе сконструировалось типом `QPolarChart`, заменив при этом сконструированное конструктором базового класса значение?

```
class PlotView : public QAbstractItemView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit PlotView(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~PlotView();

protected:
    QChart *m_chart;
    QChartView m_chartView;
};

PlotView::PlotView(QWidget *parent) :
    QAbstractItemView(parent),
    m_chart(new QChart),
    m_chartView(m_chart)
{
}


class PolarPlotView : public PlotView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit PolarPlotView(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
};

PolarPlotView::PolarPlotView(QWidget *parent) :
    PlotView(parent),
    m_chart(new QPolarChart)//?
{
}
```

Comment: Ну, работайте в теле конструктора, но  смущает такая инициализация в базовом классе. Смущает еще и `m_chartView(m_chart)` - в наследнике нужно рвать эту связь. Может, вам стоит строить иерархию на абстрактном классе? Или по крайней мере передавать указатель на chart конструктору, возможно, со значением по умолчанию?

Comment: @Harry, если в конструкторе выполнять оператор delete для m_chart и тут же создавать в нем новый объект - это нормально? Не будет подводных камней?

Comment: Это попытка получить BMW, привязывая (бечевкой) соответствующие запчасти к велосипеду...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class PlotView : public QAbstractItemView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit PlotView(QWidget* parent = nullptr) :
        QAbstractItemView(parent),
        m_chart(new Chart())
    {
    }
protected: 
    // Конструктор для наследников
    PlotView(QChart *chart, QWidget *parent = nullptr) :
        QAbstractItemView(parent),
        m_chart(chart)
//...
```

При наследовании

```
class PolarPlotView : public PlotView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit PolarPlotView(QWidget *parent = nullptr):
        PlotView(new QPolarChart(), parent)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Гениально! Никогда бы не подумал, что конструктор может быть protected.